# "The controller with the name 'CustomersController' is not registered," when creating an unnamed app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I believe Angular 1 creates an app or module even when you specify an unnamed `ng-app` directive like so:

`<div ng-app = ""><div>`

Using Angular 1.6, I declare an module/app and a controller declaratively and provide a constructor function for the controller. I believe Angular picks up the fact that the constructor function I have defined is for the said controller based on the naming convention, so I do not need to explicitly register or associate the controller with the app, though I can.

Here is what I did in HTML, and I got an error implying that my `CustomersController` was not registered.

```
<html>
  <body data-ng-app = ""
        data-ng-controller = "CustomersController">

    <!-- Stuff -->

    <script src = "angular.js" type = ...></script>

    <script>
      function CustomersController($scope) {
        $scpope.customers = ... // yada

        $scope.customers.add = function() { ... } // yada
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I got the same error even when I changed the HTML to the following:

```
<html data-ng-app = "">
  <body data-ng-controller = "CustomersController">

    <!-- Stuff -->

    <script src = "angular.js" type = ...></script>

    <script>
      function CustomersController($scope) {
        ...
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The error message reads, "The controller with the name 'CustomersController' is not registered."

Comment: `ng-app=""` hasn't been valid syntax since 1.2.  Quite simply, this will not work.

Comment: Not even with `data-ng-app`? You mean they removed the directive altogether and now the only way to create a module is by declaring it programmatically in JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  `ng-app` must be provided a valid angular module, and the controller must be registered to this module.  Generic functions as controllers have not been valid for quite a long time (angular 1.2 is from 2014).

Comment: @Claies I was following along a video tutorial titled "AngularJS Fundamentals in 60-ish Minutes" by Dan Wahlin and practicing on the basis of that. It appears from your comments, though, that the information I am using is outdated. Is there a better video tutorial you know of that is easy to follow along and also is recent? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM

Comment: that video is from 2013, and more things have changed with Angularjs than are the same as in that video, unfortunately.  While the video does cover some crucial points that express some basics for the overall design philosophy for the framework, it can't really be used for the current state of the framework.  As to current source material, this site isn't the right resource, aside from referring to the official documentation.

Comment: it's worth noting that if you create a module, and then register the controller with the module, the majority of the rest of the examples from the video will work, at least so far as to give you a basis to study the more recent refinements;  you could study a style guide like the one written by John Papa after understanding the basics of data binding, for example....